# Getting Mercurial in-process hook to run on Windows

Tags: windows, mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

I'm trying to get a Mercurial in-process hook to run on Windows.
The problem is not how to write the hook *(I want to use an existing one, in this case [BugTracker.Net](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html)'s hook for Mercurial integration - I didn't find a direct link to the file, but you can see it if you download BT.net [here](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet_download.html), it's in the "mercurial" subfolder).*
The problem is how to tell Mercurial to run it.

I spent quite some time to read the documentation, but I'm stuck right now.
(it would probably be easier with a certain knowledge of Python - which I don't have)

I know that I have to insert a line in the hgrc file (in the .hg folder of my repository).

There's an example [in the HG Book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#id403443) which looks like this:

```
[hooks]
commit.example = python:mymodule.submodule.myhook
```

And there's another example on the [Mercurial site](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook), it looks like this:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = /path/to/changegrouphook
```

Now I want a "incoming" hook, so at least I know I have to do this:

```
[hooks]   
incoming.btnet = X
```

The problem is to figure out "X".
The filename is **hg_hook_for_btnet.py** and in the file, there is a line which looks like this:

```
def debug_out(s):
```

I suppose that's the name of the "function" itself.
So my line needs to look something like this:

```
[hooks]   
incoming.btnet = python:hg_hook_for_btnet.debug_out
```

But this gives me an error message **[Errno 2] No such file or directory** when I push.
I already tried lots of different variations, but it doesn't work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

- Do I need **python:** at the beginning or not?
- Do I need  to specify the file extension **.py** or not?
- Do I need **/path/to/...** as indicated in the example from the Mercurial site (see above)?
- If yes, what is the correct syntax for the path? (just **c:\MyRepo\** doesn't work - syntax must be different in Python)

Also, did I put the hook file into the correct folder?
Right now, it is in the main folder of my repository (on the same level as the .hg folder).

---

**EDIT:**

Martin, I changed it into this:

```
[hooks]
incoming.btnet = python:~c:\HG\MyRepo\hg_hook_for_btnet.py:debug_out
```

Now I get a different message: **[Errno 22] Invalid argument**
I suppose this is because of the `repo` and `ui` arguments you mentioned.

So, does this mean that the hook script is broken?
*(as I said - I don't know anything about Python, this is an existing hook script from an [open source bugtracker](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html))*

---

**EDIT 2:**

Sorry for the confusion regarding in-process and separate process - I know there is a difference, but I assumed that if the hook is written in Python, it must be in-process automatically (turns out I was wrong :-)

Okay, with the syntax in your edited answer, the script at least runs.
I have Python 2.7 installed (already did that before I asked the question here) and changed the first line in the script into `#!C:\Python27\python.exe`.
Now I get this:

```
running hook incoming.btnet: c:\HG\MyRepo\hg_hook_for_btnet.py
warning: incoming.btnet hook exited with status 1
```

So the script runs, but there is still some error.
This seems to be a Bugtracker.NET related problem, so I will ask on the BT.NET mailing list for further advice.
Thank you for your help though, without you I probably wouldn't even have come so far!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use

```
[hooks]
incoming.btnet = python:~/path/to/hg_hook_for_btnet.py:debug_out
```

and define `debug_out` as

```
def debug_out(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    # ...
```

as explained in the HG book -- all hooks are called with a `ui` and a `repo` argument plus some extra hook-specific arguments. The [Mercurial API](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialApi) page explains what you can do with the `ui` and a `repo` arguments.

---

**Edit:** Aha... I've now looked at [the script](http://btnet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/btnet/mercurial/hg_hook_for_btnet.py?view=markup). It is not designed to be run as an in-process Mercurial hook. It is instead designed to be run as a separate process. So you will need to use

```
[hooks]
incoming.btnet = c:\HG\MyRepo\hg_hook_for_btnet.py
```

and make sure you follow the instructions in the script: it talks about setting the path to the `hg.exe` binary and to your Python interpreter. The latter means that the author expects you to install Python. There is an email address in the script -- I suggest you contact corey Trager directly or via a BugTracker.NET mailinglist. Since it's a bug tracker, I assume they have a proper place where you can report this! :-)